# [Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'NativeGraphRequestManager.start')]

Tags: javascript, api, react-native, expo, react-native-fbsdk

Trying to implement FBSDK and UBER SDK into my app and it doesn't seem to be working. I keep getting a loading on my cover image and events won't pull through.

Here's my attempt at it!
Here's my package.json file.

```
    "react": "^16.4.1",
"react-native": "^0.55.4",
"react-native-calendar-events": "^1.6.1",
"react-native-easy-grid": "^0.1.17",
"react-native-events": "^1.0.7",
"react-native-fbsdk": "^0.7.0",
"react-native-maps": "^0.21.0",
"react-native-uber-rides": "^0.4.3",
"react-native-uber-rides-estimates": "^0.1.0",
```

Here are my declarations for fb

```
const FBSDK = require('react-native-fbsdk');                        
const {
GraphRequest,
GraphRequestManager} = FBSDK;
```

Here's my attempt at pulling events from the facebook page.

```
getFBEvents = () => {
const infoRequest = new GraphRequest(
    '/' + this.state.fbPageId + '/events',
    {
        accessToken: this.state.fbPageToken,
        parameters: {
            limit: {
                string: '1000'
            },
            time_filter: {
                string: 'upcoming'
            },
            fields: {
                string: 'description,end_time,name,place,id,start_time,ticket_uri'
            }
        }
    },
    (error, result) => {
        if (!error) {
            this.state.fbEventLoaded = true;
            let data = result.data
            RNCalendarEvents.authorizationStatus()
                .then(status => {
                    if (status === 'authorized')
                    {
                        this.saveEvent(data)
                    }
                    else if (status === 'undetermined')
                    {
                        RNCalendarEvents.authorizeEventStore()
                            .then(status => {
                                if (status === 'authorized')
                                {
                                    this.saveEvent(data)
                                }
                            })
                            .catch(error => {
                            });
                    }
                })
                .catch(error => {
                });
        }
    }
);
new GraphRequestManager().addRequest(infoRequest).start();
```

This is trying to pull cover from facebook page

```
getFBCoverPhoto = () => {
const infoRequest = new GraphRequest(
    '/' + this.state.fbPageId,
    {
        accessToken: this.state.fbPageToken,
        parameters: {
            fields: {
                string: 'cover'
            }
        }
    },
    (error, result) => {
        if (!error) {
            console.log('result.cover.source:' +result.cover.source)
            this.state.imgSource = result.cover.source
        }
    }
);
new GraphRequestManager().addRequest(infoRequest).start();
```

Trying to figure out why my data isn't pulling correctly.
 I keep getting TypeError for NativeGraphRequestManager.start() but I can't seem to figure out why. Maybe I've been pressing it too long and I'm now braindead.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Forgot the call.

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {webViewHeight: 100, imgSource: undefined, fbEventLoaded: false, fbPageId: '', fbPageToken: ''}
}

async componentWillMount(){
    this.getFBCoverPhoto()
    this.getFBEvents()
}

Comment: May be your `accessToken` in your call is `null`?